# 'Sticky' element inside a 'Fixed' element slides in the opposite direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed, sticky

I have a *child* div that needs to be positioned fixed with respect to a *wrapper* which is way up in the DOM hierarchy (instead of the viewport/parent element). I am creating a new stacking context in order to achieve this.

The *child* div also has some *sticky* elements in it. And its *parent* has horizontal scroll.

Am facing an issue when I scroll the *parent* div. It ends up sliding the sticky elements too, which is the desired behavior, but why do the elements stick to the right edge instead of left?

http://jsfiddle.net/5vhsg1Ln/2/

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>
        This is some content which is outside of ggparent div. I want the 'child' to be positioned relative to this div.
      </p>
      <div class='ggparent'>
        <p>
        This is the great grand parent. This div is vertically scrollable.
        </p>
        <div class='gparent'>
          <p>
            This is the grand parent div.
          </p>
          <div class='parent'>
            <p>
              Horizontal scroll here... This is the parent div with some text.
            </p>
            <div class='child'>
               <span class='sticky'>
                 Sticky 1
               </span>
               <span class='sticky2'>
                 Sticky 2
               </span>
               <p>
                 This is the child. Positioned fixed to wrapper.
               </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='parent2'>
            <p>
              This is another parent div with some text.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    div{border:1px solid #ddd;}
    
    .wrapper {
      transform: rotate(0deg); /* new stacking context */
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .ggparent {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .gparent{
      height: 600px;
      width: 300px;
     }

    .parent, .parent2{
      height: 300px;
      width: 200px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      position: relative; /* For the sticky element in child */
     }
    .child {
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      position: fixed; /* gets fixed to wrapper */
      top: 225px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      white-space: normal;
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: sticky;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .sticky2 {
      position: sticky;
      left: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!